# A chain of words

Tags: wordplay, word-ladder

> curlicue
>   baleful
>   running rigging example
>   passionate
>   toothy?
>   more up
>   complement of because
>   triangular cloth
>   curlicue

Replace each line above with a new two-syllable word of similar meaning that is legal in Scrabble. The last two or more letters of each new word must form the start of the next new word, and the first and last new word must be the same word. The correct answer might follow a pattern like below, for example.

> abcdefg
>   defghi
>   ghijkl
>   klmn
>   mnop
>   nopqrstuv
>   tuvwxyz
>   yzab
>   abcdefg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sequence seems to fit

> curlicue - ringlet
>  baleful - lethal
>  running rigging example - halyard
>  passionate - ardent
>  toothy? - dental
>  more up - taller
>  complement of because - ergo
>  triangular cloth - goring
>  curlicue - ringlet

Comment: You cracked it. Very good!