# A chain of words 2

Tags: wordplay, word-ladder

Replace each line below with a new two-syllable word (or three syllables, where noted) of similar meaning that is legal in Scrabble. The last two or more letters of each new word must form the start of the next new word, and the first and last new word must be the same word.

> tip the applecart
>   bulldoze
>   guitar passer
>   runs after it’s shut off
>   another place
>   really going against the grain (three syllables)
>   way
>   bad weather underground?
>   juggernaut
>   possible lawn inhabitant
>   tone down
>   rock jock’s find
>   tip the applecart

I posted this similar puzzle earlier: [A chain of words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90679/a-chain-of-words)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This chain may loop around: tip the applecart

> derail

bulldoze

> railroad

guitar passer

> roadie

runs after it’s shut off

> diesel

another place

> elsewhere

really going against the grain

> heresy

way

> system

bad weather underground?

> temblor

juggernaut

> lorry

possible lawn inhabitant

> ryegrass

tone down

> assuage

rock jock’s find

> geode

tip the applecart

> derail

Comment: Another job well done!