# A chain of words 3

Tags: wordplay, word-ladder

Replace each line below with a new word of similar meaning that is legal in Scrabble. The last two or more letters of each new word must form the start of the next new word, and the first and last new word must be the same word.

> prime example
>   itsy bitsy
>   what some swimmers do
>   floater example
>   tongue experts?
>   super ripple
>   like a buddy
>   lighten
>   pipes place
>   neurotransmitter example
>   prime example

I posted these similar puzzles earlier:
[A chain of words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90679/a-chain-of-words)
[A chain of words 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90717/a-chain-of-words-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

prime example

> nineteen

itsy bitsy

> teensy

what some swimmers do

> synchronize

floater example

> Zeppelin

tongue experts?

> linguists

super ripple

> tsunami

like a buddy

> amiable

lighten

> bleach

pipes place

> chase - a false wall which hides pipes

neurotransmitter example

> serotonin

This post is indebted to msh210's

Answer (score 3):

> three, eensy, synchronized, [educator](https://forums.atozteacherstuff.com/index.php?threads/how-does-a-floater-position-work-for-a-sub.78663/), oralists, tsunami, amiable, bleach, [chromosome?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIPES), meth, three

Comment: 1 is the right idea, but the wrong example. 2 and 3 are off by one letter each. 6, 7 and 8 are correct. (If you update your answer, I'll delete this comment to reduce confusion)